# Using XGBOOST in c++

Tags: c++, xgboost

How can I use XGBOOST https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/ library in c++? I have founded Python and Java API, but I can't found API for c++

Comment: DId you read the installation guide?

Comment: Yes, i have read an installation guide, but i can't find example of using xgboost with c++

Comment: Try to use this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744351/xgboost-prediction-is-different-for-c-and-python-for-the-same-model

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I ended up using the C API, see below an example:

```
// create the train data
int cols=3,rows=5;
float train[rows][cols];
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        train[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1);

float train_labels[rows];
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    train_labels[i] = 1+i*i*i;


// convert to DMatrix
DMatrixHandle h_train[1];
XGDMatrixCreateFromMat((float *) train, rows, cols, -1, &h_train[0]);

// load the labels
XGDMatrixSetFloatInfo(h_train[0], "label", train_labels, rows);

// read back the labels, just a sanity check
bst_ulong bst_result;
const float *out_floats;
XGDMatrixGetFloatInfo(h_train[0], "label" , &bst_result, &out_floats);
for (unsigned int i=0;i<bst_result;i++)
    std::cout << "label[" << i << "]=" << out_floats[i] << std::endl;

// create the booster and load some parameters
BoosterHandle h_booster;
XGBoosterCreate(h_train, 1, &h_booster);
XGBoosterSetParam(h_booster, "booster", "gbtree");
XGBoosterSetParam(h_booster, "objective", "reg:linear");
XGBoosterSetParam(h_booster, "max_depth", "5");
XGBoosterSetParam(h_booster, "eta", "0.1");
XGBoosterSetParam(h_booster, "min_child_weight", "1");
XGBoosterSetParam(h_booster, "subsample", "0.5");
XGBoosterSetParam(h_booster, "colsample_bytree", "1");
XGBoosterSetParam(h_booster, "num_parallel_tree", "1");

// perform 200 learning iterations
for (int iter=0; iter<200; iter++)
    XGBoosterUpdateOneIter(h_booster, iter, h_train[0]);

// predict
const int sample_rows = 5;
float test[sample_rows][cols];
for (int i=0;i<sample_rows;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        test[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1);
DMatrixHandle h_test;
XGDMatrixCreateFromMat((float *) test, sample_rows, cols, -1, &h_test);
bst_ulong out_len;
const float *f;
XGBoosterPredict(h_booster, h_test, 0,0,&out_len,&f);

for (unsigned int i=0;i<out_len;i++)
    std::cout << "prediction[" << i << "]=" << f[i] << std::endl;


// free xgboost internal structures
XGDMatrixFree(h_train[0]);
XGDMatrixFree(h_test);
XGBoosterFree(h_booster);
```

Comment: Did you get to know how to free the `const float *f;`, when I predict large amount of data, it seems that memory is not freed. I looked into the code `XGDMatrixFree(h_test)` should do it, but still the memory leak increases with the size h_test!

Comment: Sounds like the leak is elsewhere, did you confirm with Valgrind?

Comment: apparently `XGBoosterPredict` isn't thread safe, I was calling it from a large number of threads, https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/311

Comment: How did you install the library for c++? Also, what `#include`s are you using? @Tomer @Khaledvic

Comment: use `#include <xgboost/c_api.h>` don't forget to link the built xgboost libs in your make file `LDLIBSOPTIONS=../xgboost/lib/libxgboost.a ../xgboost/rabit/lib/librabit.a ../xgboost/dmlc-core/libdmlc.a`
 and off course add xgboost and rabit to the include paths (gcc command) `-I../xgboost/include -I../xgboost/rabit/include`

Comment: I made a makefile like this: 
`LDLIBSOPTIONS=xgboost/lib/libxgboost.a xgboost/rabit/lib/librabit.a 
CFLAGS=-I xgboost/include -I xgboost/rabit/includemain.cpp
all:
 g++ main.cpp $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBSOPTIONS)`
main.cpp and xgboost folder are in same directory as `Makefile`. I am getting a linking error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: btw I am using linux

Comment: on osx, added includes for ```stdint.h```, ```xgboost/c_api.h```, and ```iostream``` and successfully compiled with ```g++-6 -I../../xgboost/include -I../../xgboost/rabit/include test_xgboost.cpp ../../xgboost/lib/libxgboost.a ../../xgboost/rabit/lib/librabit.a ../../xgboost/dmlc-core/libdmlc.a -fopenmp```

Answer (score 6):

Use XGBoost C API.

```
  BoosterHandle booster;
  const char *model_path = "/path/of/model";

  // create booster handle first
  XGBoosterCreate(NULL, 0, &booster);

  // by default, the seed will be set 0
  XGBoosterSetParam(booster, "seed", "0");

  // load model
  XGBoosterLoadModel(booster, model_path);

  const int feat_size = 100;
  const int num_row = 1;
  float feat[num_row][feat_size];

  // create some fake data for predicting
  for (int i = 0; i < num_row; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < feat_size; ++j) {
      feat[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1)
    }
  }

  // convert 2d array to DMatrix
  DMatrixHandle dtest;
  XGDMatrixCreateFromMat(reinterpret_cast<float*>(feat),
                         num_row, feat_size, NAN, &dtest);

  // predict
  bst_ulong out_len;
  const float *f;
  XGBoosterPredict(booster, dtest, 0, 0, &out_len, &f);
  assert(out_len == num_row);
  std::cout << f[0] << std::endl;

  // free memory
  XGDMatrixFree(dtest);
  XGBoosterFree(booster);
```

Note when you want to load an existing model(like above code shows), you have to ensure the data format in training is the same as in predicting. So, if you predict with XGBoosterPredict, which accepts a dense matrix as parameter, you have to use dense matrix in training.

Training with libsvm format and predict with dense matrix may cause wrong predictions, as [XGBoost FAQ](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) says:

> “Sparse” elements are treated as if they were “missing” by the tree booster, and as zeros by the linear booster. For tree models, it is important to use consistent data formats during training and scoring.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need：https://github.com/EmbolismSoil/xgboostpp

```cpp
#include "xgboostpp.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    auto nsamples = 2;
    auto xgb = XGBoostPP(argv[1], 3); //特征列有4列, label有3个, iris例子中分别为三种类型的花，回归任何的话，这里nlabel=1即可

    //result = array([[9.9658281e-01, 2.4966884e-03, 9.2058454e-04],
    //       [9.9608469e-01, 2.4954407e-03, 1.4198524e-03]], dtype=float32)
    XGBoostPP::Matrix features(2, 4);
    features <<
        5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2,
        4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2;

    XGBoostPP::Matrix y;
    auto ret = xgb.predict(features, y);
    if (ret != 0){
        std::cout << "predict error" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "intput : \n" << features << std::endl << "output: \n" << y << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case training in Python is okay and you only need to run the prediction in C++, there is a nice tool for generating static if/else-code from a trained model:

https://github.com/popcorn/xgb2cpp

I ended up using this after spending a day trying to load and use a xgboost model in C++ without success.  The code generated by xgb2cpp was working instantly and also has the nice benefit that it does not have any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no example I am aware of. there is a c_api.h file that contains a C/C++ api for the package, and you'll have to find your way using it. I've just did that. Took me a few hours reading the code and trying few things out. But eventually I managed to create a working C++ example of xgboost.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem we runs the xgboost program from C++ source code.