# Linking error in C++

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation, xgboost, linker-errors

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071672/using-xgboost-in-c) gives an example of how to use [xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) - a machine learning library written in C++. I want to run the example, and therefore install the library for C++. I added the `/lib` files to `/usr/local/lib` and `/src` files to `/usr/local/src`

I am able to compile this much part of the example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xgboost/c_api.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int cols=3,rows=5;
    float train[rows][cols];
    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            train[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1);

    float train_labels[rows];
    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        train_labels[i] = 1+i*i*i;
    DMatrixHandle h_train[1];
    XGDMatrixCreateFromMat((float *) train, rows, cols, -1, &h_train[0]);

}
```

However, I am getting a linking error:

```
/tmp/ccuBacNh.o: In function `main':
TerrainPredict.cpp:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `XGDMatrixCreateFromMat'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I resolve this. I concluded that cpp files are missing, but I don't know where to put them. I want help regarding how to proceed with installation.

I also tried using a makefile:

```
LDLIBSOPTIONS=xgboost/lib/libxgboost.a xgboost/rabit/lib/librabit.a xgboost/dmlc-core/libdmlc.a -lpthread
CFLAGS=-I xgboost/include -I xgboost/rabit/include -I  dmlc-core/include
all:
    g++ main.cpp $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBSOPTIONS)
```

I put Makefile, main.cpp and xgboost directory in the same folder.
In that case I am getting a longer linking error. Error is too long to include fully. [Here](https://pastebin.com/dJVuDmyL) it is.

Comment: try adding `-lpthread` to the end of your LDLIBSOPTIONS

Comment: That did not change much. The starting lines changed to something like `xgboost/lib/libxgboost.a(sparse_page_writer.o): In function `xgboost::data::SparsePage::Writer::Writer(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, unsigned long)`
`

Comment: Do you want the entire output?

Comment: What you just posted is saying where an error occurred but you did not post the actual error message part

Comment: Include the entire output in the question

Comment: I made some changes in the make file as well

Comment: You also need to link the right library for OMP (i'm not sure what that is called)

Comment: Most likely omp stands for OpenMP which is supported by g++ 6.2.0 (my version)

Comment: Adding the -fopenmp flag worked. Thanks!