# XGDMatrixCreateFromMat fails after previous DMatrix is used by the booster

Tags: c++, xgboost

If below code path is repeated in the same process more than once, XGDMatrixCreateFromMat fails with -1 during second visit. For reference, I followed [Using XGBOOST in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071672/using-xgboost-in-c).

But, If I remove the use of `dtrain` (`XGBoosterCreate` and the successive calls) in the booster, calling multiple times `XGDMatrixCreateFromMat` succeeds in the same process, but of course the point of creating the DMatrix is to be able to use with the booster for prediction. Please note that the below code path works when called multiple times from different processes.

```cpp
DMatrixHandle dtrain[1];

XGDMatrixCreateFromMat(reinterpret_cast<float*>(copied_inputs), 
 data_size, input_dim, -1, &dtrain[0]);
XGDMatrixSetFloatInfo(dtrain[0], "label", copied_labels, data_size);

XGDMatrixCreateFromMat(reinterpret_cast<float*>(copied_test_inputs), 
 test_data_size, input_dim, -1, &dtest);
XGDMatrixSetFloatInfo(dtest, "label", copied_test_labels, test_data_size);

XGBoosterCreate(&dtrain[0], 1, &h_booster_);
for (auto param : hyper_params_) {
    XGBoosterSetParam(h_booster_, param.first.c_str(), param.second.c_str());
}
for (int iter = 0; iter < num_boost_round_; ++iter) {
    XGBoosterUpdateOneIter(h_booster_, iter, dtrain);
    const char* eval_out;
    XGBoosterEvalOneIter(h_booster_, iter, &dtest, &evnames, 1, &eval_out);
}

std::cout << "Deleting dtrain: " << XGDMatrixFree(dtrain) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Deleting dtest: " << XGDMatrixFree(dtest) << std::endl;

std::cout << "XGBoosterFree: " << XGBoosterFree(h_booster_) << std::endl;
```

How do I create new DMatrix and use it in booster multiple times in the same process.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the actual error, by adding the following line.

```cpp
if (XGDMatrixCreateFromMat(copied_inputs, data_size, input_dim, -1, &dmat) != 0) {
  std::string error_s(XGBGetLastError());
  std::cout << error_s << std::endl;
}
```

The error was `There are NAN in the matrix, however, you did not set missing=NAN`. This hinted me that there was a problem the way I created the `float*` input. Although, it runs without a problem first time, but the result probably was wrong. I was constructing a `copied_inputs` like below

```cpp
float** copied_inputs = new float*[input_size];
float* copied_labels = new float[input_size];
for(size_t i = 0; i < input_size; ++i) {
  for(size_t j = 0; j < input_dim; ++j) {
    copied_inputs[i] = new float[input_dim];
    copied_inputs[i][j] = static_cast<float>(inputs[i][j]);
  }
  copied_labels[i] = static_cast<float>(outputs[i]);
}
```

The above construction of `copied_inputs` is clearly wrong as the way it is accessed in the `XGDMatrixCreateFromMat` is:

```c
  for (xgboost::bst_ulong i = 0; i < nrow; ++i, data += ncol) {
    xgboost::bst_ulong matj = 0;
    for (xgboost::bst_ulong j = 0; j < ncol; ++j) {
      if (common::CheckNAN(data[j])) {
      } else {
        if (nan_missing || data[j] != missing) {
          data_vec[offset_vec[i] + matj] = Entry(j, data[j]);
          ++matj;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So, I changed my `copied_inputs` construction to:

```cpp
  float* copied_inputs = new float[data_size * input_dim];
  float* copied_labels = new float[data_size];
  float* temp_copied_inputs = copied_inputs;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < data_size; ++i, temp_copied_inputs += input_dim) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < input_dim; ++j) {
      temp_copied_inputs[j] = static_cast<float>(inputs[i][j]);
    }
    copied_labels[i] = static_cast<float>(outputs[i]);
  }
```

And that solved the problem of multiple runs.